How to remove row on client side by jQuery based on key auditor id and budget year?
I work on jQuery with asp.net . I face issue I can't remove row from grid view based on key AUD_RECID and P_BUDGET_YEAR .
AUD_RECID with different P_BUDGET_YEAR so I need key will be both from AUD_RECID and P_BUDGET_YEAR
SO I will have unique  Value when remove row and it will remove it success based on key contain both (AUD_RECID,P_BUDGET_YEAR)
I can't add P_BUDGET_YEAR with AUD_RECID to be one key for remove this is my issue .
code below working when remove based on AUD_RECID  so
my modification need add P_BUDGET_YEAR  with AUD_RECID   to be as key when delete
what I try as below
1- When press delete row on every row on grid view .
function ADD_AUDITORWithComplain() {
  
       
        success: function (Result) {
         

            $.each(Result.d, function (key, value) {

                if (value.Status == "1") {

                    if (value.ADDED_AUDITORS_INFO != null) {
                        if (value.ADDED_AUDITORS_INFO.length > 0) {
                            $("#gvP_AUDITORS").empty();
                            var rowNo = 1;
                            for (var i in value.ADDED_AUDITORS_INFO) {

                              
                                var row = "<tr align='center' id='tr" + value.ADDED_AUDITORS_INFO[i].AUD_RECID + "' class='record clickable-row'> " + "<td class='tdCount'>" +
                            
                                    (rowNo) + "</td><td>" +
                                    value.ADDED_AUDITORS_INFO[i].AUD_DESC + "</td> <td>" + value.ADDED_AUDITORS_INFO[i].P_BUDGET_YEAR + "</td> <td>" +

                                    " <a href='#' id='" + value.ADDED_AUDITORS_INFO[i].AUD_RECID + "' class='delbutton btn btn-outline-danger' onClick='DELETE_AUDITOR_CONFIRM_COMPLAIN(\"" + value.ADDED_AUDITORS_INFO[i].AUD_RECID +
                                    "\",\"" + value.ADDED_AUDITORS_INFO[i].P_BUDGET_YEAR +
                                    "\",\"" + "هل انت متأكد ؟" +
                                    "\",\"" + "سيتم حذف المراقب : " + value.ADDED_AUDITORS_INFO[i].AUD_DESC +
                                    ", هل تريد المتابعة ؟" + "\");return false;' data-toggle='tooltip' title='" + value.ADDED_AUDITORS_INFO[i].AUD_DESC + " '> حذف</a>" +

                                    " </td></tr>";


                                row = $(row).hide();
                                $('#gvP_AUDITORS').append($(row));
                                rowNo++;


                                $(row).fadeIn(1000);

                            }
                        }
                    }
   

             

                }
              
            });
        }
       
    });
}

2- when click yes or no for confirm dialog
function DELETE_AUDITOR_CONFIRM_COMPLAIN(AUD_RECID, P_BUDGET_YEAR,
    title, message) {

    if (custom_confirm(title, message, (ans) => {
        if (ans) {
            DELETE_AUDITOR_COMPLAIN(AUD_RECID, P_BUDGET_YEAR);
            return true;
        } else {

            return false;
        }
    }) == true) {

        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

}

3- WHEN change id for delete I need to  be based on AUD_RECID and P_BUDGET_YEAR
function DELETE_AUDITOR_COMPLAIN(AUD_RECID, P_BUDGET_YEAR) {


 
       
        success: function (Result) {
       

            $.each(Result.d, function (key, value) {

                if (value.Status == "1") {
                    if (AUD_RECID == "") {
                        $("#gvP_AUDITORS").empty();
                    }
                    else {

      

                        var btnDeleteID = AUD_RECID;
                        var record_id = $('#' + btnDeleteID).attr("id");


                     
                        var tr_id = $('#' + btnDeleteID).parents(".record");


    
                        tr_id.css("background-color", "#F2DEDE");

                     
                        tr_id.fadeOut(500, function () {

                            //Remove GridView row
                            tr_id.remove();
                            totalRows = $("#gvP_AUDITORS tr").length;
                            if (totalRows < 2) {
                                $("#gvP_AUDITORS").empty();
                            }
                            var i = 1;
                            $('#gvP_AUDITORS > tr > .tdCount').each(function () {
                                $(this).text(i);
                                i++;
                            });
                        });
                    }

                   

                }
                
            });
        }
    });
}

updated post
parts I need to add P_BUDGET_YEAR
1-  var row= ...ETC
2-
  var btnDeleteID = VIOLATION_RECID;
                     


                        //Get the GridView Row reference
                        var tr_id = $('#' + btnDeleteID).parents(".record");

